# change mysql pivot table code into php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to instead Null to 0 and add subtotal at the end of column and row.
how can I change?

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
  'sum(case when gameid = ''',
  gameid,
  ''' then score end) AS ''',
  gameid, ''''
)
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  scores;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT playerid, ', @sql, '
              FROM scores
               GROUP BY playerid');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
  'sum(case when gameid = ''',
  gameid,
  ''' then score else 0 end) AS ''',
  gameid, ''''
)
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  scores;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT coalesce(playerid, ''Column Total'') as playerid, ', @sql, ', sum(score) as row_total
              FROM scores
               GROUP BY playerid WITH ROLLUP');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The `else 0` takes care to deliver 0 instead of null.
The `WITH ROLLUP` together with the `coalesce(playerid, ''Column Total'')` takes care of the column totals,
and the `sum(score) as row_total` takes care of the row totals.

Comment: I am not an PHP specialist. And the original question was a database one, not a PHP one. However, look at the last value of the `@sql` variable to see the statement you have to build, and execute it. The main input is the distinct list of `gameid`s.

Comment: do I need store the mysql code in a file and let php call it?

Comment: @user2389248 how is the mysql code called currently from PHP?