# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll

Tags: php, mysql, pivot

I have try the following code but the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object", anyone can help?

```
   $query = "SET @sql = NULL;".
   "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
   CONCAT('sum(case when gameid = ''',gameid,''' then score else 0 end) AS ''',gameid, '''') 
   INTO @sql ".
   " FROM  scores;".
   " SELECT @sql; ". 
   " prepare stmt FROM @sql; ". 
   " execute stmt;"; 

   $result_array = array();
   $queryku = $db->query($query); 
   $result_array = $queryku->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
   var_dump($result_array);
```

Comment: Is $ db setup as a pdo object?

Comment: I imagine your call to `$db->query($query);` is failing, causing `$queryku` to be assigned a value of `null`. Are there any errors displayed?

Comment: You need to check that your database calls are working. I suspect that the `query()` call is returning false, but if you check the errors from the database, you'll see why

Comment: I bet $queryku is false or null.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what it is - it's just not an object :)

Comment: Is your $db object initialize properly ?

Comment: the output is Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/a4685009/public_html/allscores.php on line 84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that your query is invalid. You missed essential part which concatenates a string that contains conditional aggregation that you made on your columns (which you produce with your first SELECT with GROUP_CONCAT) with a string that contains an actual SELECT from your table.

Instead you wrote

```sql
SELECT @sql;
```

Which returns a string to the client.

But right after that

```sql
prepare stmt FROM @sql;
```

is failing for the above mentioned reason.

Now to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18703411/1920232) you've got an answer with something that looks like a proper code. To simplify calling this code from php I'd strongly suggest to wrap it into a stored procedure

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_pivotscores()
  SET @sql = NULL;
  SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
      CONCAT(
    'sum(case when gameid = ''',
    gameid,
    ''' then score else 0 end) AS ''',
    gameid, ''''
  )
    ) INTO @sql
  FROM  scores;

  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT coalesce(playerid, ''Column Total'') as playerid, ', @sql, ', sum(score) as row_total
                FROM scores
                 GROUP BY playerid WITH ROLLUP');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you php code might look like

```php
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db_name;charset=UTF8', 'user', 'password');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    $query = $db->prepare("CALL sp_pivotscores()");

    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Exeption: " .$e->getMessage(); //TODO better error handling
    $result = false;
}
$query = null;
$db = null;

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I already let the db connect at a file at the start include("includes/sqlconnect.inc"); then do I still need connect DB again ?

Comment: If you already have a open connection to the db then no you don't need  to connect again. I just provided you with boilerplate code that allows to get the resultset.

Comment: @user2389248 Did it help after all?

Comment: @user2389248 First of all you probably have to learn how to appreciate the time and work of those who are trying to help you by [upvoting and accepting the answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). For now as I see you've asked 5 questions but didn't bother to accept any of the answers.

Comment: @user2389248 Now instead of asking the same question again and again getting the next answer from another community member you better [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18777849/edit) your current question and post your table schema and some sample data desired output. And then your problem can be solved.